# How to make Parallel Independent Task to Call WCF in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, task-parallel-library, task

I'm calling the Service Methods using Task Factory

Let us consider the Client Code:

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
Task task1=
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                var List1 = client1.GetList1(););

Task task2=
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                var List2 = client1.GetList2(););

Task task3=
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                var List3 = client1.GetList3(););

// and so forth

taskList.Add(task1);
taskList.Add(task2);
taskList.Add(task3);

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

Now How the Service receives the request ? it's receives in Parallel or Serial ? If it is Serial means how could I make it as Parallel ?

Comment: Is this a wcf service?

Comment: Yes. its a WCF Service.

Answer (score 0):

For a wcf service, you can skip the client side task generation altogether.

These two work perfectly together, if the server side implements `IServer` and the client side uses `IAsyncServer`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServer
{
    [OperationContract]
    int DoStuff1();

    [OperationContract]
    int DoStuff2();
}

[ServiceContract(Name = nameof(IServer))]
public interface IAsyncServer
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<int> DoStuff1();

    [OperationContract]
    Task<int> DoStuff2();
}
```

A client doing

```
var task1 = server.DoStuff1();
var task2 = server.DoStuff2();
```

will trigger both actions, one after the other, but the second can start before the first is finished. To get the results, do something like

```
var result1 = await task1;
var result2 = await task2;
```

when you need the respective result.